# Is iOS keychain API thread safe? Getting duplicate item exceptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, keychain

I am working on an iOS app where potentially an SDK can send notifications to the app simultaneously in many different threads and try to write some items in the keychain. Before adding an item to the keychain, my code (obviously) checks if the item is already present in the keychain and if so it throws a `errSecDuplicateItem` duplicate item exception.

Off-late, I have noticed crashes pertaining to the duplicate item exception while some process tries to add/write a value to the keychain.

Now, my question is, AFAIK, keychain APIs are thread-safe and reentrant in nature.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/working_with_concurrency

However, since the exception in my case is thrown by `errSecDuplicateItem`, it definitely looks like a thread sync issue. Perhaps, even if keychain APIs themselves are thread-safe, the usage flow (things happening in different threads, etc.) in my case might cause that sync issue. For now, I have decided that it's a good idea to treat the adding of the item in the keychain piece as a critical section (so I have but the whole code inside `@synchronized(self) {}`) and to see if we can reproduce the error again.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Sure “thread safe” doesn’t mean you get to stop following best practices for avoiding accessing shared resources. The usual way is just use GCD to ensure all accessed are on the same serial queue.

Comment: "Thread safe" in other words does not relieve you of the responsibility of making your _own_ code thread safe! You must still behave coherently for your own usage. "Thread safe" just means the thing you are talking _to_ won't crash just because you're using threads.